# How to read the contents of a text file?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, file-browser

We can define a `StringProperty` and set its `subtype` to `FILE_PATH` in order to select a file:

```
file_path: StringProperty(
    name = "File Path",
    description = "A path",
    subtype = "FILE_PATH")
```

**Q:** How can I get the actual content (text) of the selected file?

Comment: Hi and Welcome. What do you mean by "inside of it" exactly? Also, might be a good idea adding your code to the question. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the question clear enough now? This is the second question I put, so it is not that good.

Comment: Yep, that's better @Pat. I recommend take a basic python course. How to read a text file: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-plain-text-files-in-python-3

Answer (score 7):

#### [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path)

Recommend for paths, using [**`pathlib`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module.

For the most part this is a [**generic python question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list). The blender specific part is making the path absolute if given as a blender relative path, prefixed with `"//"`

[image]
*Relative chosen when setting path property in file browser*

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path


#path = some_object.filepath # as declared by props
path = "//tmp/foo/bar.txt"  # a blender relative path

f = Path(bpy.path.abspath(path)) # make a path object of abs path

if f.exists():
    print(f.read_text()) # read and print.
```

The site https://medium.com has some great articles on [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and its usage:

- https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f
- https://medium.com/@webology/pathlib-is-wonderful-9d25919469d3
- https://medium.com/swlh/five-most-useful-pathlib-operations-77f9c96790b3

Comment: Cheers. Feel free to edit in missing links.

Comment: 24 downvotes? I'm sorry, I feel responsible for that. Most likely the reason why OP (the other pat) was removed. I should edit the other answer to get 24 downvotes too, lol. But I guess my edit gets reverted anyway because as we know by now, some users don't like any critics or suggestions to improve answers or even having a hard time accepting a better one for whatever reason...

Comment: Wild stats, voting isn't a thing obviously... might be nice having this on meta. Btw, yet another pat: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/98123/pat

Comment: May find this interesting: 12 upvotes on old posts in one day (never happend to me in 3 years): https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/94339/patisawesome200?tab=reputation

Comment: Having a hard time finding a good quote from Dr. Watson. lol. Feels like: https://i.giphy.com/media/aVCTDsm7XY6Pu/giphy.webp and https://i.giphy.com/media/26gJzdwIgfiDBChDa/giphy.webp

Comment: Have a soft spot for the Nigel Bruce version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes_(1939_film_series)

Comment: OMG. Good to know. 19 up-votes in a row is danger to the public! Precise observation Mr. Holmes... arrest him again! Bad news is that since the votes are corrected there is no chance to find the up-voter anymore, I'll keep my eyes open and give my best Mr. Holmes.

Comment: If the answers would help, I wouldn't mind... Ok, we'll see how good the machine handles that.

Comment: I guess we can't do much, not the type of guy who betrays someone. Might help to tell him that we noticed that, we'll see...

Comment: No reply on my [comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180092/how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-text-file/180209#comment343524_180209) yet, but no further fake votes at least.